# parse a collection of object and know which one matches

Tags: powershell, comparison

Say I have an array called $basket.

And I run the following check against $basket

```
$basket.fruit -imatch "\bapple\b"
```

Now if I want to take the whole object where $basket[x].fruit matches "apple", is there a quick way to do it, or would I only achieve this via a for loop, iterating every object in $basket to compare it with the string "apple" ?

I would like to return the line of the array $basket where the property fruit matches the string "apple" and I am wondering if there is an easy way other than using for/foreach/do/while etc... loops.

Sorry if the question seems daft but I am relatively new to the concept of objects and was wondering if there is a quick way to extract any $true comparison off the box here.

EDITING MY QUESTION, REPHRASING :
Put it this way, I have a first collection of :

```
$array[0].string="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
$array[1].string="One bird in the hand is worth 2 in the bush"
```

then I have :

```
$regex[0].reg="dog"
$regex[1].reg="bird"
```

What I want to end up with is (for example):

```
$result[x].string="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
$result[x].match="dog"
```

Given that both input arrays have thousands of records.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Where-Object cmdlet to filter out objects in the array that match the specified predicate (? is an alias for the Where-Object cmdlet):

```
$baskets = @()

$baskets += [pscustomobject]@{fruit='banana'}
$baskets += [pscustomobject]@{fruit='apple'}
$baskets += [pscustomobject]@{fruit='kiwi'}
$baskets += [pscustomobject]@{fruit='apple'}

$baskets | ? { $_.fruit -imatch '\bapple\b' }
```

Comment: interesting!
What if I want to add a member say "keyword" and the value would be "apple" for all $baskets += [pscustomobject]@{fruit='apple'} ? How can I proceed ?
Thanks!

Comment: It's OK, I actually found a way around using your technique above so I consider the question answered! thanks!